# Why is my Office 2010 download always resulting in “installation of this package failed”?

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

Everytime I visit https://www20.downloadoffice2010.microsoft.com/usa/registerkey.aspx?ref=backup&culture=en-US In order to download a backup up copy of both a "MS OFFICE 2010 Home and Business" install and a "MS OFFICE 2010 Home and Student" install, however the exe files they provide both give the following error upon execution: "The installation of this package failed." I have (and provide on the website) the valid license keys for both of these products.

I don't know if it matters or not, but I am downloading the installation files on a Windows 7 64-bit machine, but trying to install them (one Home and Business and the other Home and Student) on two different XP 32-bit machines.

I thought that the error could be caused by the website providing 64-bit Windows 7 installs because it read the specs of the machine that is downloading them. However, if I attempt to execute these installation files even on the machine that downloaded them, I still get that error.

Also, if it matters, the browser used to download the installation packages is a fully up-to-date Google Chrome browser, AND I have made sure to uninstall any previous versions of MS Office on the 32-bit machines

**--------UPDATE-------------**

After comparing the previous and current sizes of these downloaded installation files, it seems that they are different (and in both cases, considerably smaller than they should be). So, I can only infer that while Chrome made it look like the files were fully downloaded, they were for sure not completely downloaded. I am now trying to download them in IE instead, in the hopes that Microsoft can get their site to work with their own browser since many times it appears that they can't with others. At least, it seems, I can more easily keep a close watch on the files as they download.

Does this sound about right to anyone else?

**--------UPDATE AGAIN-------------**

Okay so at some point during these downloads it just hangs up and then treats the incomplete file as though it were a virus capable of bringing down the pentagon, NORAD, NASA, and the entire state of New York simply because it can't recognize the publisher. And, it considers the file a complete file, instead of just a part of a file, which it is. After calling Microsoft support and having them send me some secondary link, I was finally able to get this downloaded.

Comment: Microsoft just sucks